# How to Like a FeedItem with apex code

Tags: apex, chatter

We have Requirement where we need to display the chatter Feeds in a visual force page without using the standard chatter tags . i have displayed the feeds in table ,now my requirement is i need to like a feed with apex code .am unable to figure it out could you guys help me to sort it out .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these methods:

`ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.likeFeedItem(String communityId, String feedItemId)`
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_likeFeedElement)

`ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.likeComment(String communityId, String commentId)`
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_likeComment)

Comment: so, on clicking Like (button), I should call this method passing the feedItem Id? (how do I pass the parameter on button click to the method?)

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy If you are in LWC you'll want to capture the `onclick` event of your like button and then send it up to your Apex controller, which can then fire the `likeFeedItem()` method.